# Install app widgets on Android Go?

Tags: app-widgets, android-go

I have already used this website to determine that I cannot put widgets on my home screen because of the version of Android Go I have installed.

What version or launching app in general would be the best option all around and of course would allow me to have widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Nova Launcher](https://novalauncher.com/).  It gives you a very customizable UI and allows widgets.

> - Customizable UI
>   Control your desktop, app drawer, dock and folders
> - Icon Themes
>   Customize the icons on your device to fit your personal tastes
> - Backup and Restore
>   Easily save and reload any and all of your custom setups

I am not associated with it.  They have a prime version (paid up), which has more features and taht is what I am using.